# Where is dask.datasets?

Tags: dataframe, dataset, dask

I'm trying to follow some examples on Dask's website for Bags and DataFrames. The examples require me to use datasets: dask.datasets but I didn't get datasets with my installation as far as I can tell, i.e. I get an error telling me dask has no attribute datasets, and I don't see it in the dask folder.

I can't find help using Google or Dask's website. Where is datasets?

https://examples.dask.org/bag.html
https://examples.dask.org/dataframe.html

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dask.datasets` was introduced in version `0.18.2`, so check your version to make sure you have `0.18.2` or later. To install the latest release (as of today), run:

```
pip install dask==2.10.1
```

Comment: This answers my question. When I installed it just recently I ended up with an earlier version somehow. Thanks.